# How to add custom Opencv library into pycharm

Tags: opencv, pycharm, openvino

Basically I am developing a project using OpenVino and OpenCV,to do so I cannot use the normal and easy way of using pip to install opencv library but instead Intel provided their own optimized version OpenCV.

I cannot find a place to add the path for the custom OpenCV in pycharm.
If anybody can enlighten me,please do so.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try the below steps.

Install Python 2.7.10

Install Pycharm(If not installed previously)

Download the OpenCV executable.

Install OpenCV

Add OpenCV in the system path(%OPENCV_DIR% = /path/of/opencv/directory)

Goto C:\opencv\build\python\2.7\x86 folder and copy cv2.pyd file.

Goto C:\Python27\DLLs directory and paste the cv2.pyd file.

Goto C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages directory and paste the cv2.pyd file.

Goto PyCharm IDE and goto DefaultSettings>PythonInterpreter.

Select the Python which you have installed on Step1.

Install the packages numpy,matplotlib and pip in pycharm.

Restart your PyCharm.

PyCharm now has OpenCV library installed and working.

Hope this will solve your issue